# Constantly check SerialPort object to see if any bytes exist and if so read bytes and perform function

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, background, lag

I am interfacing with a device, and need a way to constantly check if any bytes are available to be read by the serialport, and if so I need to read them and perform different functions. I can't create a data_received event for a number of reasons due to the project I am working on. As of now I have an infinite for loop running in a new thread, but it is causing the computer to slow way down.

Does anyone have any other ideas? Any help is appreciated. Below is the for loop code I am currently using.

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        object[] parameters = (object[])e.Argument;
        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)parameters[0];
        agentRadio agentR = (agentRadio)parameters[1];

        for (; ; )
        {
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (port.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        byte value = (byte)port.ReadByte();

                        if (value == Global.OFF_CHAR)
                        {
                            port.Close();
                            Global.isConnected = false;
                            Form form = new Form();
                            form.deviceDisconnect(agentR);

                            MessageBox.Show("Your device has disconnected on its own, due to inactivity or because a key was switched off.", "Device Disconnect", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

                            break;
                        }
                        else if (value == Global.WARNING_CHAR[0])
                        {
                            if (Global.activeClick)
                            {
                                port.BaseStream.Write(Global.POLL_CHAR, 0, Global.POLL_CHAR.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {  }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The DataReceived event is specifically intended so you don't have to write code like this.  Removing the BytesToRead test will otherwise instantly solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the horrible 'if (port.BytesToRead > 0)' polling loop!  Why do you do that - you do nothing else if the check retuns false, so just let the read block in the normal way.

Comment: By default the ReadTimout property is set to InfiniteTimeout, so the code would sit in the ReadByte method waiting for data.  The slow down you are seeing might be from double read (one from polling, one from reading).

Comment: I have a read timeout set to 5000 milliseconds elsewhere in my code, so it is not stuck waiting for anything, or at least it shouldn't be. And don't I need to polling loop? Without it it would be trying to read a byte when there wasn't one there and causing timeout exceptions unnecessarily.

Comment: 'so it is not stuck waiting for anything' - that's exactly the problem - it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DataReceived` event.  This event is called on a secondary thread, there's no need to create another, or event a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: My concern with using a data-received event is that I need something I can pause and resume or dispose/reinitialize with different functions that will need to be called elsewhere from my code. Because I manually read thousands of bytes without the data-received event and I need to be able to do so at will should the user click a different button to load/send settings; is it possible to pause and resume a data-received event, or maybe change handlers one does something, the other just ignores everything?

Comment: Pause and resume receiving from a serial port?  If you do that, you risk losing data.  It could overflow the buffer it has and by the time you do read the data, some may have been lost.  You can "pause" using the data received event simply by buffering the data as you receive it and processing that buffer when you see fit (i.e. when you resume or before you pause).